# How i can filter array by another array if 1 of elements equal?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

My array for filter:

```
types: [
  { type: 0, name: 'Item_1' },
  { type: 1, name: 'Item_2' },
  { type: 2, name: 'Item_3' },
  { type: 3, name: 'Item_4' },
  { type: 4, name: 'Item_5' },
  { type: 5, name: 'Item_6' },
  { type: 6, name: 'Item_7' },
]
```

filterBy:

```
sort: [1, 2, 3];
```

How i can do smth like this but for multiple values?

```
    filterType(item) {
        return item.type.toString() == this.sort;
    }
```

UPDATE:
Need for this function:

```
filtered() {
        const conditions = [];


        if (this.sort) {
            conditions.push(this.filterType);
        }

        if (conditions.length > 0) {
            return this.types.filter((dessert) => {
                return conditions.every((condition) => {
                    return condition(dessert);
                })
            })
        }

        return this.types;
    }
```

I already treid to make for and foreach loop but it doesn`t work

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243372/discussion-on-question-by-aurorame-how-i-can-filter-array-by-another-array-if-1).

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```js
const types = [
  { type: 0, name: 'Item_1' },
  { type: 1, name: 'Item_2' },
  { type: 2, name: 'Item_3' },
  { type: 3, name: 'Item_4' },
  { type: 4, name: 'Item_5' },
  { type: 5, name: 'Item_6' },
  { type: 6, name: 'Item_7' },
];

const needTypes = new Set([1, 2, 3]);

const filterTypes = (arr) => arr.filter(item => needTypes.has(item.type));

console.log(filterTypes(types));
```

I used `new Set()` because if `needTypes` will be a very large array then it will take much time to search in array element every time

Comment: don`t work for me

Comment: So [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the array? @aurorame

Comment: my bad, confused, but that solution don`t work for me

Comment: But it _does_ work. But if you can't explain what output you want you're not going to get answers you want. @aurorame. Is a it stringified array? Is it an array of stringified objects? Is it just a string of those objects?

Comment: @Andy i update my question

Comment: @aurorame My output is same as you said me in comments

Comment: @aurorame Why did you remove "Accepted answer" mark?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a `class`. So pass in the `types` array, and the `sort` array, and then call the class's `filter` method to return those filtered objects.

Something like this.

```js
class Desserts {

  constructor(types, sort) {
    this.types = types;
    this.sort = sort;
  }

  add(obj) {
    this.types.push(obj);
  }
  
  updateSort(n) {
    this.sort.push(n);
  }

  filter() {
    return this.types.filter(dessert => {
      return this.sort.includes(dessert.type);
    });
  }

}

const types = [{type:0,name:'Item_1'},{type:1,name:'Item_2'},{type:2,name:'Item_3'},{type:3,name:'Item_4'},{type:4,name:'Item_5'},{type:5,name:'Item_6'},{type:6,name:'Item_7'}];

const sort = [1, 2, 3];

const desserts = new Desserts(types, sort);

console.log(desserts.filter());

desserts.add({ type:7, name:'Item_8' });
desserts.updateSort(7);

console.log(desserts.filter());
```